# Is it possible to compute this integral analytically?

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Define an integral as follows

$$\small{h(\theta)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(r_1)(1-f(r_1\cos\theta+r_2\sin\theta))+f(r_1\cos\theta+r_2\sin\theta)(1-f(r_1))]\phi(r_1)\phi(r_2)dr_1dr_2}$$
where $\phi(r)$ is the probability density function of standard normal distribution, and $f$ is
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=1,\ &&x\geq s\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2s},\ &&x\in (-s,s)\\
&=0,\ &&x\leq -s
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

(1) I have tried the case of $s=0$, so that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=1,\ x\geq 0\\
&=0,\ x< 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The integral equals to $\frac{\theta}{\pi}$.

(2) However, I was not able to compute for the case of $s\neq 0$. Is it possible to compute this integral analytically in this case?

Many thanks for all comments and helps.

Comment: While there might be a nice form for all values of $s$ and $\theta$, there are some analytic forms for certain values of $\theta$.  For instance when $\theta=\pi$, $h(\pi, s)=-\frac{(s-1) (s+1) (2 \Phi (s)-1)}{2 s^2}-\frac{e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } s}+1$ where $\Phi(.)$ is the cumulative distribution function for the unit normal distribution.  When $\theta=\pi/2$, then $h(\pi/2, s)=1/2$ for all $s\geq 0$.

Comment: @JimB Thanks Jim, my goal is to obtain the integral as a function of $\theta$.